# Load vector features without adding the layer to the map in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

Is it possible to make a vector source load and reload features without adding/removing its parent layer to the map? I need to do that after my `viewparams` url variable changes.

My vectore source looks as follows

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
        var url  = 
            'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS' +
            '&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=by:data' +
            '&outputFormat=GML3' +
            viewparams;
        return url;
    },
    format: new ol.format.WFS()
});
```

I've tried calling `source.refresh()` and `source.changed()` but it won't work.

Comment: Try `source.clear()` or `source.clear(true)`  See https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/7044#issuecomment-317665872

Comment: Thanks for the link @Mike. `source.clear()` does work but only when the layer is added to the map. Is there a way to load the source without adding the layer to the map?

Comment: Instead of specifying url in the source xhr or fetch the url then read and add the features from the response `source.addFeatures(source.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.response));`

Comment: Does this assume defining a custom xhr loader function [based on the example from the api docs](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html) or is it possible to utilize the `ol.featureloader` module somehow? If you wish to post it as an answer I would mark it as resolved. Thanks.

Comment: No, a loader function only loads when required (so it needs to be on the map), just fetch or xhr the url and process the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to http://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/igc.html except using a single url

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.WFS()
});

var url = 
    'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS' +
    '&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=by:data' +
    '&outputFormat=GML3' +
    viewparams;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        source.addFeatures(source.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.response));
    }
};
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.send();
```